# Каким образом сделать?pyTelebot

Tags: python, telebot

Вопрос от новичка:
После нажатия на кнопку "узнать погоду" если человек ошибся с названием города БОТ ему отвечает, что "введи еще раз, не могу найти такой город", всё работает и Бот пишет это, но если после этого ввести название города, то он отвечает " не знаю такого ответа..." то есть исполняет **условие** из функции `weather`
Необходимо чтобы если человек ошибся с названием города, то БОТ ему говорил что нет такого города и просит ввести название заново(это работает), допродолжая эту часть до нужного результата, а не перескакивало... ломаю голову....

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def weather(message):

    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Узнать погоду':
            city_two = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "Хорошо, {0.first_name} \nВведи название интересующего тебя города".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me))
            bot.register_next_step_handler(city_two, send_weather)

        elif message.text == 'Пожелание на день':

            wishes = [
            "Желаю в новый день новых успехов и решения старых проблем. Удачи!", 
            "Пусть этот день дарит тебе только положительные эмоции и интересные встречи",
            "Хочу пожелать, чтобы твой новый день был солнечным, удачным и интересным!", 
            "Желаю хорошего дня! Пусть всё, что задумано, выполняется без труда!", 
            "Надеюсь, что твой день пройдет хорошо! С нетерпением жду встречи вечером!",
            "Пускай сегодня тебе всё удаётся быстро и без труда! Хорошего дня!", 
            "Пусть новый день подарит тебе успех в делах, приятное общение и душевное спокойствие", 
            "Желаю чтобы у тебя сегодня всё получилось!", 
            "Ты сегодня прекрасно выглядишь!"
            "Получай позитива от всего с чем сегодня встретишься"
                ]
            random.shuffle(wishes)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, wishes)
        else:
            bad_answer = "{0.first_name}, Я не знаю что ответить :(\nПопробуй ещё раз".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, bad_answer)

def send_weather(message):
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    try:
        observation = mgr.weather_at_place( message.text )
        w = observation.weather
        temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
        answer = " В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status + "\n"
        answer += "Температура на данный момент около " + str((round(temp))) + "\n\n"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , answer)
    except NotFoundError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Не могу найти такой город\nВведи еще раз")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй заново отправить register_next_step_handler на send_weather

```
a = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Не могу найти такой город\nВведи еще раз")
bot.register_next_step_handler(a, send_weather)
```

Лично у меня все работает